Is it easy/possible to handle http requests via GitHub?
Context: I'm trying to save data from a unity project to a public webpage.
All I need to do is save a string, then pull it with a different computer, I already have a script that parses that string into usable data for my project.
I set up a github project with a single .txt file, and written a pretty simple function which successfuly pulls that text (in c#):
IEnumerator GetRequest()
    {
        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(myURL))
        {
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();
            Debug.Log("Received: " + www.downloadHandler.text);
        }
    }

It's worth noting, I haven't actually used UnityWebRequest before, so the above is probably pretty dodgy.
The trouble I've hit is that I can't find a way to edit that text file remotely - Googling has turned up Octokit but it seems to be a dead end (I've barely touched .NET programming before but from what I know it's completely incompatible with unity??). My current plan is to sent a post request using a similar method to the above, and have a script (presumably this will have to be in html?) running through GitHub Pages to output the contents to my .txt file.
I'm extremely new to http and network programming in general, so please forgive me if this is a stupid question!
edit - context I added in a comment:

I should probably have mentioned this in the main post but it's a
public scoreboard (just storing usernames and scores). I did look into
a few hosting options but the only free options I found had really low
monthly request limits, which obviously doesn't work so well if
players update their entry multiple times per session. @BugFinder
above mentioned Google Drive as a possible alternative - are you aware
of some resources or keywords I can use to find out more about that
option (and do you agree that it's viable?) I'm happy with a
non-optimal solution for the short term [with plans to just pay for proper hosting later]


Github is not really a place to edit files from. Google drive can.. but normally it would be easier and simple to do it from your own webserver

Why Github though? Are both devices in the same network? In such case you could simply host a file server yourself and have full control over permissions and API ...

Supabase or another similar service should work here. GitHub (Pages) won't.

GitHub isn't really the place to do that kind of stuff. The best thing you can do is set up a local webserver like Apache and serve all the content from there.
I'd also suggest you learn at least the basics of networking and the HTTP protocol to better understand your problem and how to solve it. Don't worry it's really simple stuff.
If you need the server to be publicly available on the Internet, there are a lot of paid and free hosting platforms, just make sure not to include sensitive information on there.

I've barely touched .NET programming before but from what I know it's completely incompatible with unity??

I don't know where you found this, but it's just plain false. C# (the language used by Unity) runs on .NET. Unity just added various classes to make it compatible with the engine (very simplified).

Thanks for the info! I should probably have mentioned this in the main post but it's a public scoreboard (just storing usernames and scores). I did look into a few hosting options but the only free options I found had really low monthly request limits, which obviously doesn't work so well if players update their entry multiple times per session. @BugFinder above mentioned Google Drive as a possible alternative - are you aware of some resources or keywords I can use to find out more about that option  (and do you agree that it's viable?) I'm happy with a non-optimal solution for the short term
